# Performance Profiling Application written in c++ on android for knowing execution time / compilation time

Tags: profiler

I am having a Graphics application using GL API written in c++ and using openGL compiler  to compile it.

i am looking ways how can i profile the application along with compiler ( i am having access to compiler code too which i can change for my usage and is in C++).

i am mainly looking for ways i can profile related to compilation , how much time it was taken by compiler functions while compiling C++ application.

i had tried using timer API but if there is some profiling tool like gprof in android which i can use it will be easy for me.

i read about Traveview but i think its meant for mainly java application.

any suggestion will be highly use to me.

Comment: What exactly do you want to measure? Compile time, or your app's run time (in particular function)? Why would you need to modify your compiler for this?

Comment: i am working on writing the GL compiler that's why need to know the performance of compiler. i want to measure mainly compile time ( time in between compiler functions ) so that i can optimize compiler better.

Comment: Change your tags, it's not too much of Android in this.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to make your app run faster, and you have source code and can run it under a debugger, you can use [this technique](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/926266/performance-optimization-strategies-of-last-resort/927773#927773).

If you want the compiler to run faster, and you have source code and can run it under a debugger, you can use the same technique.

If you had gprof, you could use it, but you would be disappointed, for [these reasons](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1777556/alternatives-to-gprof/1779343#1779343).